# Issue with reinstalling MySQL Not showing the installation page rather shows the update product

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector, uninstallation, reinstall, connector-net

I am trying to reinstall MySQL which I had uninstalled about a year ago. However after running the mysql installer the installation page is not shown rather shows the update product i.e.  update Connector/NET.

I have already uninstalled the Connector/NET from my system. Incase I have also removed it from the registry using the registry Editor. I have tried multiple times but it is not working for me. I am not being able to install MySQL

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.